# Why "conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'passed' to data type int" even when using range filter

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using following code, but getting error.

> conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'passed' to data type int

```
Try
  con.open()
    Dim query = "update NTable SET Semester=Semester+1 WHERE Semester BETWEEN 1 AND 8 "
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.close()
    con.open()
    Dim query2 = "update NTable SET Semester='Passed' WHERE Semester=9"
    Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand
    cmd2 = New SqlCommand
    cmd2 = New SqlCommand(query2, con)
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.close()
    display()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: You question not have full details like table desing and its datatype

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim query2 = "update NTable SET Semester='Passed' WHERE Semester=9"
```

what datatype for Semester column as you update string value, but in first query you update integer value.

In this Semester variable what you stored ? string value or integer ? Show variable declaration line.

```
 Dim query = "update NTable SET Semester=Semester+1 WHERE Semester BETWEEN 1 AND 8 "
```

Comment: I am using varchar for storing semester in sql

Comment: i am assume Semester column datatype  is integer, bcz first query accept semester+1 as integer value, but in second query u pass string value.Better provide table design structure(Table Desing)

Comment: Form your query u can understand , first query you update semester value without single quotes , so it integer, but in second query you try to update semester value with single quotes, as it is string value.

Answer (score 0):

According to your first `UPDATE` that is successfuly processed, the `Semester` column in the database is a *Numeric* data type.

In your second update you are trying to assign a character typed value `'Passed'` to the same column. That is the issue that the error message is specifically referring to, not the `WHERE` clause as you have assumed.

This looks like a common typo, you can cut'n'pasted the query without updating the target field correctly. The solution is to change your query to `SET` the actual field that will accept the value `'Passed'`.

Assuming that the column is called `Result`, the following statement would be expected:

```
Dim query2 = "update NTable SET Result='Passed' WHERE Semester=9"
```

Comment: you mean i have to make new column "Result" for passed out students?...aslo i am using varchar as datatype for semester

Comment: Your SQL and the Intent seem to conflict, please post your schema in the form of a `CREATE TABLE` statement, then I can specifically answer your request.